# Некорректное распознавание речи при использовании Yandex SpeechKit

Tags: java, распознавание-речи, yandex-speechkit

Я пишу метод для распознавания речи с использованием Yandex SpeechKit Cloud API. В тестовом режиме на вход подаётся аудиофайл в формате wav. С помощью метода `Files.readAllBytes` файл становится байтовым массивом `bytes`.

```
public static String speech_to_text(byte[] bytes)
{
    String res = "";
    try {

        Settings set = new Settings();
        String topic = "queries";
        String lang = "ru-RU";
        String uuid = "01ae133b744628b58fb536d496daa1e6";
        URL sUrl = new URL("https://"+"asr.yandex.net"+"/asr_xml"+"?uuid="+uuid+"&key="+set.YANDEX_API_KEY+"&topic="+topic+"&lang="+lang);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) sUrl.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "audio/x-pcm;bit=16;rate=16000");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Host", "asr.yandex.net");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Transfer-Encoding", "chunked");

        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
        out.write(bytes);
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        System.out.println("Done");
        System.out.println();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(
                        conn.getInputStream()));
        String decodedString;
        while ((decodedString = in.readLine()) != null) {
            res += decodedString;
        }

        conn.disconnect();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return res;
}
```

В аудиофайле находится эталонный голосовой запрос - "Расходы Ярославской области на образование в 2016-м году". Проблема заключается в том, что распознавание речи срабатывает, мягко говоря, некорректно и возвращает мне вот такую строку:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><recognitionResults success="1">  <variant confidence="0.87">бачок</variant>  <variant confidence="1e+03">урок</variant></recognitionResults>
```

Сразу хочу отметить, что модуль распознавания речи был написан ранее на питоне и шарпе, где тот же аудиофайл распознавался адекватно.

Если кто-то сталкивался с подобной проблемой, подскажите пожалуйста, как вы её решили.